# Selenium 3.0 Firefx Driver fails with org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

Selenium 3.0 Firefx Driver fails with org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "..<Path>../geckodriver.exe");
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);


Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@23aa363a, browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@23aa363a, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.0', revision: '350cf60', time: '2016-10-13 10:48:57 -0700'
System info: host: 'D202540', ip: '10.22.19.193', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:135)
```

Comment: same situation on linux looking for a solution

Comment: how did you solve it @lese ?

Comment: This problem has been solved using Selenium Webdriver 3.3.1 and Geckodricer v0.15

Answer (score 6):

this issue is solved with geckodriver 0.15 and selenium 3.3 version.

Comment: This made me realize that for geckodriver 0.17 you need Selenium 3.4.0

Comment: I still have the same problem with geckodriver 0.20.1 and Selenium 3.11.0. Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969902/geb-geckodriver-not-working-properly-launching-multiple-browser-window

Answer (score 1):

You need to download geckodriver. And then set

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path\\to\\geckodriver.exe")
```

Check this [link](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/launching-firefox-browser-with-geckodriver-selenium-3).

Comment: I am setting the System property but still getting the error,        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "..<Path>../geckodriver.exe");
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

Comment: How are you writing the path to the geckodriver.exe?

Comment: The path format should be "D:\\work\\project\\geckodriver.exe".  It will not work if you just set the path as you just wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it with this. It seems it could not find the firefox binary

```
capabilities.setCapability("firefox_binary","C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. It was solved opening Eclipse/Netbeans with admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

This worked (linux mint, opensuse thumbleweed, win7)
with

> libraryDependencies += "org.seleniumhq.selenium" %
>   "selenium-firefox-driver" % "3.0.1"
>
> geckodriver.exe -V
>   geckodriver 0.13.0

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("linux")) {
  println("загружены настройки os.name=linux")
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "bin/chromedriver")
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "bin/geckodriver")

}else{
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "bin\\chromedriver.exe")
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "bin\\geckodriver.exe")
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "bin\\IEDriverServer.exe")
  System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Web Driver\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe")
  System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "c:\\XXX\\operadriver.exe")

  System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.path","""C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera""")
  System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.binary","""C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Opera\\launcher.exe""")
  //
}
```

...

```
      case
        "firefox" => {
        println(" подгружаем Веб-драйвер: geckodriver")
        //iniprofile = new ProfilesIni()
        //ffprofile = iniprofile.getProfile("default")
        dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox()
        dc.setCapability("gecko", true) // как выйдет драйвер, так и установить
//        dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, ffprofile); //FirefoxDriver.PROFILE = “firefox_profile”;
        remote = new FirefoxDriver(dc)
      }
```

but, for Remotewebdriver-connection if previous session failed,cancelled or aborted we get error:

```
[info] XXXX.E011_WebDB6292 *** ABORTED ***
[info]   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Session is already started (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
[info] Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
[info] Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
[info] System info: host: 'XXXX', ip: '172.16.4.125', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_11'
[info] Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today, and it appears that **not being admin on my laptop is actually an issue**. To resolve it

- Install in a non admin way Firefox (just need to click on no when Windows ask for privilege elevation)
- Use the exe path (for my system something like `C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\AppData\\Local\\MozillaFirefox\\firefox.exe`).

  It actually solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you dont want to download the Gecko driver, you can downgrade the Firefox version to 44.

https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Install-and-Update/Install-an-older-version-of-Firefox/ta-p/1564

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest GekoDriver then better to update the Selenium library versions as well.
The above issue is related to the Selenium version.