# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities while trying to launch Firefox with Selenium v3.8.1

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, mutablecapabilities

I am not able to launch Firefox browser using **geckodriver** in **Selenium 3.8.1**

This is my code

```
public class LoginTest {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Test
    public static void logintest() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        dc.setCapability("marionnete", true);
        constants.driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
        constants.driver.get("https://www.amazon.in");
        constants.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        constants.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
```

I am not able to understand why it is not working and always giving an exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException`: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12- 01T18:33:54.468Z'<br>
System info: host: 'ABC-VAIO', ip: '192.168.1.209', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_161'<br>
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

Comment: First of all make sure your **geckodriver version** is compatible with the **Selenium version**. This is the number one mistake when using Selenium with any browser. Make sure the capabilities you provide are correct and you didn't forget anything. Best is to look out for the official examples or a program from somebody else that works. In doubt, try out older driver versions with older Selenium versions.

Comment: I was using selenium 3.8.1 and downloaded latest gecko driver from github, also how can i check the compatibility.

Comment: Selenium is already at 3.11 ... 'Support is best in Firefox 55 and greater, although generally the more recent the Firefox version, the better the experience as they have more bug fixes and features', see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver

Comment: Yes i know i forcely downgraded to 3.8.0 because it was also not working for 3.11

Comment: Possibly this is the same issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106844/selenium-3-0-firefx-driver-fails-with-org-openqa-selenium-sessionnotcreatedexcep

Comment: The last time I used Selenium with Firefox, I used **Selenium 3.4.0** on **Firefox ESR 45** with **geckodriver v0.15.0 for arm7hf**. This were my `Capabilities`: https://i.imgur.com/974pD4k.png (see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/67631) for more)

Comment: I have downgraded selenium to 3.0 and downgraded gecko driver to 0.15 and now browser got launched but not getting maximized and getting exception: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown error has occurred
Build info: version: '3.3.0', revision: 'b526bd5b41', time: '2017-03-07 1

Answer (score 0):

You should add capabilities for firefox Please modify your code as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
capabilities.setVersion("your firefox version");
capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in");
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

...implies that the FirefoxDriver didn't find a matching set of capability while initiating a new *WebBrowser* session.

You are using *Selenium Client* **v3.8.1** but the *Release Notes* of *Selenium Client* **v3.7.0** clearly states that :

```
* Migrated from using `DesiredCapabilities` to either
  `MutableCapabilities` or (preferably) `ImmutableCapabilities`.
```

So, you have to use the [**`merge()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html#merge-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) method from [**`MutableCapabilities`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/MutableCapabilities.html) Class to add the capabilities within an instance of [**`FirefoxOptions`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html) and pass the *FirefoxOptions* object while initializing the *Firefox Browser* as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
dc.setCapability("marionnete", true);
FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
opt.merge(dc);
constants.driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);
constants.driver.get("https://www.amazon.in");
```